# A syntax error when create MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION count(name varchar(20))
        RETURNS integer
        BEGIN
        DECLARE d_count integer;
                select count(*) into d_count
                from ins
                where ins.name = name
        RETURN d_count;
        END
```

the SQL code above show there is a syntax error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN (d_count); END' at line 8
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: missing ; after  select count(*) into d_count
                from ins
                where ins.name = name

Comment: So... add that semicolon

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN (d_count);
 END' at line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error, you miss `;` after the SELECT statement -

```
CREATE FUNCTION count (name varchar(20))
RETURNS integer
BEGIN
  DECLARE d_count integer;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_count FROM ins WHERE ins.name = NAME;
  RETURN d_count;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION count(@name varchar(20))
        RETURNS integer
        BEGIN

        RETURN( select count(*) 
                from ins
                where ins.name = @name);

        END
```